# Be able to hide the 'Explore our questions' header

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

Can there be an option to hide the 'Explorer our questions header'?

1. Most of them are in my favorite tags anyway.
2. I know how to use the site.
3. It is taking screen estate I can use for the question list.

> [image: screen shot]

Comment: *Feeling lucky to be out of the test group*. The more I see, the less I like this new navigation. Too bad it's probably going to take over anyway.

Comment: Yes, the dark side is gaining strength ;)